# R Making barplot

Tags: r

Im trying to make a barplot with the following data

```
      Dept
Admit        A   B   C   D   E   F
Admitted    601 370 322 269 147  46
Rejected    332 215 596 523 437 668
```

and I have tried the following code:

```
admission_department <- barplot(biasUCB_d, main="Admit by deparment",
                                xlab="biasUCB_d[['Dept']]", 
                                col=c("darkblue","red"),
                                legend = rownames(biasUCB_d[['Dept']]), 
                                beside=TRUE)
```

The name of the coding used to create the dataset is:

```
biasUCB_d <- margin.table(UCBAdmissions, c(1,3))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Dept is an element of a list this should work:

Data:

```
biasUCB_d <- list(Dept = read.table(header=T, text='
Admit        A   B   C   D   E   F
Admitted    601 370 322 269 147  46
Rejected    332 215 596 523 437 668'))
```

Solution:

```
dmission_department <- barplot(as.matrix(biasUCB_d$Dept[2:7]), main="Admit by deparment",
                               xlab="biasUCB_d[['Dept']]", 
                               col=c("darkblue","red"),
                               legend = biasUCB_d$Dept$Admit, 
                               beside=TRUE)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
admission_department <- barplot(biasUCB_d, main="Admit by deparment",
                                xlab="Department", 
                                col=c("darkblue","red"),
                                legend.text = rownames(biasUCB_d), 
                                beside=TRUE)
```